# Using Magento as the main, and creating a single sign on to integrate with other third party software

Tags: api, magento, session, integration

This has been something I have been trying to work on for a good long time. It first started with Prestashop as an integration with other scripts or pieces of the puzzle I needed to make for an overall website. I am currently still using Prestashop as my webstore but have since switched to Magento.

I switched to Magento because of it's complex flexibility and because overall I think it is the best solution, best backing and best overall eCommerce script to go with.

That being said, the same issues I was having with Prestashop appear to be the same I will continue to have any in aspect that I try to integrate things together in perfect harmony.

I have Magento setup, as the main portion of the website, and inside Magento in sub folders I have Wordpress installed in a folder called "articles" and I have also went with FluxBB as my message forums because of it's simplicity in not having a crap load of bloated extra features that I could care less about and that is in a sub folder called "forums".

From this point, we know that Magento, Wordpress and FluxBB all have their own way of managing users; creating, managing, and tracking them.

What I am wanting to do is find the best way to fit these three and more together for my website to make the experience for the customer as smooth and as functional as possible. After emailing the ever talented and helpful Alan Storm, he told me the best solution he was aware of working was to make a third party user management that they all point to and it manages the customers authentication. I do believe his thoughts may be the best but I wanted to put this out there here on StackOverFlow and I may post this on Magento as well to get the broad scrope of magento developers and smart guys that like challenges.

I have several thoughts, none may work, some may work half ass, or one may just be something workable. But first let me tell you what I have accomplished so far. I have done the necessary steps to integrate my overall design for the header and footer, so essentially Wordpress and FluxBB are wrapped and are contained inside Magento's outer design layer. So with that being said I have also made it where Magento will check the session to see if the user is logged in to Magento or not by saying "Hello Guest" or "Hello User". This is where I have hit a stopping point because I am out of my depth and would like assistance, whether it is something we create together out of pure challengeness or someone says if I pay them they will help me, either way I would like this accomplished. If and when I get the code figured out whether by means of paying for assistance of a group effort I would like to make it freely available for others to use the concept for their own projects.

---

**Brain Fart #1:**

Adjust the user tables for both Wordpress and FluxBB to conform more to the structure of Magento, as for the password and username/email login portion. The rest of the fields can respectively stay as they are for post counts, and etc.

From there, I would like to figure out which class in Magento does the actual input into the database when a customer is created out of registration. When I find that code, I would like to extend upon it the ability to copy the user credentials into the other two tables in the database for Wordpress and FluxBB. If necessary it can just be an added couple of fields to Wordpress and FluxBB if that seems like a better idea and yes I do mean the actual encrypted password that Magento creates, I want this to be secure as well.

From there, when we know that a customer registers with Magento the data is copied over to the other two tables then we at least have made progress, whether this progress will actually work, is still to be determined.

We then disable the login/logout and registration links in any way that we can from Wordpress and FluxBB because they will no longer be needed because we want the user to register, login and logout through one location which is Magento.

Then comes the fun part in my eyes, keep the damn session going throughout the entire website as they order products, review wordpress articles and possibly leave comments, send to friends and etc.... as well as post topics, replies and etc in the FluxBB capacity.

To me this is where the creating the fields or adding the data from Magento's customer registration comes into play, I can make it check to see if they are logged into Magento already and from there we may be able to have it validate itself. This may be over kill or this may just be how it needs to be done. But to me if the credentials are located in all three databases then they should be able to be validated by changing the code in Wordpress and FluxBB or adding code. And Yes I am aware that we will also have to do something about Profile Editing and Password Editing if a customer so desires to change their information.

But that is my first thought on this whether it is the right decision or not, I would like hear from the vast knowledge of people here who have more experience and knowledge than I get with Magento, PHP and everything else.

---

**Brain Fart #2**

This illogical idea seems like an outside stretch entirely to me because of the complexity of Magento and how it is overall setup.

But the idea is to remove/edit the Wordpress and FluxBB (and any other third party software) to pretty much ignore it's own method of registration, login, logout, edit and look to Magento for it's credentials and establishing new customers. Essentially making them an oversized module of Magento.

I just know that the way Magento is setup is to be modulerized and its complexity seems like it would take a lot more coding and troubleshooting to do this.

---

**Brain Fart #3**

Dump both Wordpress and FluxBB and look towards modules in the Magento Connection Store that pretty much has all of the functionality that I need and can add to them what is missing and not mess with trying to integrate third party software.

I love Wordpress, I think replicating it with a module, at least after the hours I have spent looking at all of the modules available that are CMS/News related is a tough call. FluxBB I could take it or leave it, if someone had an already viable solution to use phpBB or vBulletin or SimpleMachines I would go with them. I rather it be free open source software, not because I am a cheap skate but just because I support open source as much as I can.

---

**Brain Fart #4**

Can this be a cookie this, but would only be effective if they allow cookies, or could somehow addon to the session to allow things to pass through but Magento sets up different sessions or allows you too so they things to crash against each other so this may not at all be an idea or may be one as well.

---

I know I am not giving examples of things I have tried, files I have looked at or anything related to that and I apologize, I provide some links related but nothing specifically found so far that matches what I am trying to accomplish. And I have tried to merge things together with some fun disastrous results.

**Link Examples?:**
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/customer#customer.create
http://www.magentogarden.com/blog/how-are-passwords-encrypted-in-magento.html
http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/customers_and_accounts/registration_fields
[How to access Magento customer's session from outside Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982210/how-to-access-magento-customers-session-from-outside-magento)

Any assistance with this would be nice, I am trying to work on several parts of the website at once and this one is troublesome and I would say that everyone is going to find it hard or have found it hard. Anyone like challenges? :)

--------- EDIT:

I have got Magento and Wordpress to work perfectly together with James Kemp's module found on CodeCanyon's website (Single Sign-On for Magento and Wordpress) and I am going to adapt it to work for FluxBB or anything else I do.

Just passing along the information... I see this was edited, don't know what was edited and don't care. Just passing along information I have since found since posting this.

Comment: That is one novel of a question -- if you ever write a blog entry anywhere about your progress, please post a link here!

Comment: Pretty interesting to see how you worked through this. We were talking about how to go about this (just between wp and magento though) a while back at work and didn't really come up with a solution. I'll have to pass this on. Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on This is why OpenID and Facebook connect were created to help solve this same problem but on a larger broader scale.

Comment: In line with "Brain Fart #1" specifically for wordpress - When a user creates a Magento account, you could pragmatically create a wordpress account using the same email/password: https://tommcfarlin.com/create-a-user-in-wordpress/ . Then anytime they login using Magento, you can pragmatically log them into wordpress too: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon

Answer (score 1):

I am managing/customizing a combo of magento+vanilla forums+a custom app made in Yii framework. The users are "shared" between the apps. None of the two links are good. As Alan already replied to you, the correct SSO will be with an external user database/manager. But well, not everyone is up to recoding three apps just to get 1 post a week forum and 1 article a month blog to work with magento. So we are left with less options. First of all, if you don't want (most probably not) to rewrite a good portion of already written open source project that is being updated and maintained and then maintain your changes against periodical updates (you want them), then you have to duplicate the user data over three databases. Unless the project you adapt has some way to manage users data as plugin or external module. AFAIK both of your choice don't.

So, how to implement it? Assuming you choose Magento as mother-of-all, you need it to export an API for authentication, which may work over browser using cookies and javascript but this is rather tricky, or you can use it's frontend cookie to validate the sessions doing server-server API requests from children apps. This is a preferred option as far as "classical" SSO goes. Technically, what should happen when your users open forum or blog, the respective apps detect magento's cookie and check if the session is valid and who is the user. If the user is found, his data is copied to the blog or forum tables.  Then you need to start an authenticated session on blog or forum app using the newly created user record.

So far so good, but yet some work. you need to disable the user profiles management in the children apps or modify it so the data held in Magento is always the correct one and you need to invent something to synchronize the Magento's representation of user profile down to the children. This is better to be hooked up on Magento's events so every time a user changes his profile the data is updated in the children app. But there is another but too. You probably want to keep some data app specific, a display name on the forum is not necessary the FirstName+LastName from the Magento and some would like to keep it private.

The above is just what I can recall as interesting facts about keeping it running. There are certainly many other things I've left out, more or less specific. But hopefully my comment can help your brain farting.

We've tried to evaluate other options but anything without duplicate data seems to be too expensive to implement or to maintain. Maybe later. With budget and time.