# I can't get customer session in my magento external site (same domain)

Tags: php, magento, session, backend

I'm developing a small application into magento folder, i.e (magento/myApp).

I'd like to get the customer session in my magento/myApp folder once a customer have logged in from Magento site, I mean, get the session in my external folder.

I'm doing this:

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name"=>"frontend"));
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session", array("name"=>"frontend"));

if(!$session->isLoggedIn()){ 
 //Do something
}
else {
//Do something else
}
```

I've tried different ways to get customer session in my external site, and I couldn't.

My magento version is: 1.7.0.2. I've searched a lot in internet, and not found nothing yet. Just get customer session into my external site (same domain).

This is my `System`->`Configuration`->`Web`->`Session Validation Settings`:

```
Use SID on Frontend: YES.
```

Comment: This is not completed code. Did you add `Mage.php` file before the code block that you wrote above?

Comment: Also, magento cookie should available in source domain. Check settings and set cookie domain.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to access Magento customer's session from outside Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982210/how-to-access-magento-customers-session-from-outside-magento)

Also you will need to include `Mage.php`

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn());
?>
```