# Session Variable outside magento

Tags: php, magento, variables, session, magento-1.9

I have to read a `$_SESSION['name']` in a file outside magento or better is in /magento/folder. 
I tried any solution without good result.

Example

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setUName($_SESSION['username']);
```

In external file use this code:

```
require_once("../app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app();

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::init();

$_SESSION['username'] = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getUName();
```

Result??? Variable empty....

I'm crazying with magento.... I need this one variable!!!!

If someone can help me I'll say thanks.

Comment: See if this works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954182/get-cart-content-outside-of-magento-but-on-same-domain/28954802#28954802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'))->getUName();
```

Explanation:

Session start here: Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start()

When default magento is trying to start session it runs with param: **$sessionName = 'frontend'**. When you run **Mage::getSingleton('core/session')** - you instantiate session without any params. And you didn't pull necessary session. So that because you need to add one more param with session name

Comment: thks ... you saved my life..... sry but I can't put +1 in your reputation because my reputation is low ...

Comment: Hi @zhartaunik: Do you know how we can get the same thing with 'customer/session' ?