# Get external session in Magento

Tags: php, session, yii2, magento-1.9

I am running a website in Yii2 framework i.e. example.com
And I have also a Magento shopping website in the same domain i.e. example.com/shop

Now I want to use the user session of Yii2 in Magento so that the user logged-in in Yii2 will be logged-in in Magento.

I have user session in Yii2, but when I print session in Magento it shows different session. 
I have also tried these:

[Session Variable outside magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422106/session-variable-outside-magento)

[Magento Session from external page (same domain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764296/magento-session-from-external-page-same-domain)

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14921/login-into-magento-from-outside-of-magento-without-ruining-session

but I did not get the solution.

P.S. I am new in Magento. Magento version is 1.9.1.1

Is it possible to use external session in Magento?
If yes then how?

**EDIT**
My question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764296/magento-session-from-external-page-same-domain). 
That question is about accessing Magento session in external file. But I want external session inside Magento.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento Session from external page (same domain)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764296/magento-session-from-external-page-same-domain)

Comment: This question is not duplicate. See edit.